# Ports not receiving fetch request in k8s

Tags: node.js, express, kubernetes, fetch, port

I have a k8s cluster running locally on an arm Mac. I have client and server pods. The client is a React frontend. The server is an express server connecting to a mongodb Atlas cluster.

So far the images build fine and all pods are running.

The problem is the internal port routing is not working. All I see is

```
GET http://localhost:5000/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

And the referrer policy in the networking tab suggests a CORS error:

```
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

I'm not sure what I need to do to get my client to fetch on a certain port? So far I have this, which works outside of k8s:

```
const getAllUsers = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/")
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((res) => {
        return setUsers(JSON.parse(res));
      });
  };
```

The server has this code to handle the request:

```
  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  usersCollection
    .find()
    .toArray()
    .then((results) => {
      res.json(results);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
});
```

My server cluster ip service is like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: server
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

And my server deployment is like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: mydocker/k8s-server
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
          env:
            - name: REDIS_HOST
              value: redis-cluster-ip-service
            - name: REDIS_PORT
              value: "6379"
```

When I log out the server deployment logs I get:

```
> express_mongodb@1.0.0 dev /app
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.12
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Connected to Database
listening on 5000
```

Which is great - it's listening on the port I specified with

```
 app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log("listening on 5000");
});
```

There's something I'm not getting here. The first thing I want to do is make sure my server is connected to my client on port 5000 - what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: After a long time looking at CORS error fixes, maybe it isn't a CORS error? I curl the service ip with:

```
curl my.ip.##.##
```

Then try:

```
curl localhost:5000
```

But the requests time out.

I use `kubectl describe service server-cluster-ip-service`

and get back

```
Name:              server-cluster-ip-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            <none>
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          component=server
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.###.##.##
IPs:               10.###.##.##
Port:              <unset>  5000/TCP
TargetPort:        5000/TCP
Endpoints:         172.##.#.##:5000,172.##.#.##,172.##.#.##
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you should be using the service name to communicate with different services inside the cluster.

If you react server want to talk with the express server, you have to the `express-service-name` as host into the **react** service. Kubernetes will auto manage the resolution.

so for you, it will be `server-cluster-ip-service`

```
const getAllUsers = () => {
    fetch("http://server-cluster-ip-service:5000/")
      .then((res) => res.text())
      .then((res) => {
        return setUsers(JSON.parse(res));
      });
  };
```

As in a single machine or in a host all services can talk to each other on **localhost** the same way in Kubernetes cluster services uses the service name to solve each other.

Reference document DNS for services & POD: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

You express cluster POD or application will run on `0.0.0.0/0` and port `5000` and there will be one **Kubernetes service** as your created now with `target port 5000`.

Your client or other application internally will call this service by **service name** and request redirected to container (POD) of the express server.

Comment: This isn't working yet - it calls the server-cluster-ip-service, but I still get a CORS error